# How to stop/wait a Windows batch till powerpoint file loads in Browser

Tags: windows, batch-file, powerpoint, windows-scripting

I have a Windows Batch file which opens a powerpoint file in browser using direct link, I want to capture File Loading time.

The script which I have is

```
@echo off

rem Get start time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

start chrome.exe https://filelink.com

rem Get end time:
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)
```

Actual file loading from browser takes time, but with this I am not able to capture the actual, How can I wait till the file completely loads and then run end time command !

Thanks

Comment: Your use of the `Start` command means that the `Get end time:` code will execute immediately upon starting `chrome.exe`, All this does is effectively time the `start chrome.exe` command not the `chrome.exe https://filelink.com` execution. I would suggest that if you want to time the duration your chrome.exe instance was openened for, you remove the `start` command completely. If that's not what you're trying to achieve, _bearing in mind that batch files do not interact with browsers and their opened web pages_, please try to explain what you're trying to time.

Comment: You can't. Unless you are willing to host a web browser control in a custom application, there's no way for you to assign to events (like document fully rendered).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
start chrome.exe https://filelink.com
```

I would try something like

```
powershell.exe (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://filelink.com', 'output.log')
```

or download a windows version of 'wget'

Comment: If I have to do it using powershell or wget, I wouldn't have mentioned specific for windows batch